# Unable to rename and delete media files from media player app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, file, exoplayer-media-item

I have made a media player app using Exoplayer. I am trying to implement the rename and delete functionality on the individual media files. But the operations are not working and **file.renameTo(newFile)** always returns false. I have checked other answers on StackOverflow about file permissions but it is not working. Please help!
Here is the code-
**For deleting file**

````
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                            alertDialog.setTitle("Delete");
                            alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to delete this file?");
                            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    Uri contentUri=null;
                                    if(mediaType.equals(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO))
                                        contentUri= ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                                Long.parseLong(mediaList.get(holder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()).getId()));
                                    else if(mediaType.equals(MEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO))
                                        contentUri=ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                                Long.parseLong(mediaList.get(holder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()).getId()));
                                    else
                                        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "wrong media type!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    File file=new File(mediaList.get(holder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()).getPath());
                                    Log.i(TAG+" ###",""+file.getName());
                                    boolean delete=file.delete();
                                    if(delete)
                                    {
                                        context.getContentResolver().delete(contentUri,null,null);
                                        mediaList.remove(holder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition());
                                        notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition());
                                        notifyItemRangeChanged(holder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition(),mediaList.size());
                                        Toast.makeText(context,"File deleted successfully!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Toast.makeText(context,"Media file deletion failed!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }

                                }
                            });
                            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                            alertDialog.show();
                            bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });```

**For renaming file-**
```bsView.findViewById(R.id.bs_rename).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                            alertDialog.setTitle("Rename To");
                            EditText editText = new EditText(context);
                            String path = mediaList.get(holder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()).getPath();
                            final File file = new File(path);

                            String mediaName = file.getName();
                            mediaName = mediaName.substring(0, mediaName.lastIndexOf("."));
                            editText.setText(mediaName);
                            alertDialog.setView(editText);
                            editText.requestFocus();
                            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    //Apply validation check
                                    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText().toString()))
                                    {
                                        Toast.makeText(context,"Can't rename empty file",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    String onlyPath = file.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath();
                                    Log.i(TAG + " ###", "Original Path: " + onlyPath);
                                    String ext = file.getAbsolutePath();
                                    Log.i(TAG + " ###", "ext: file.getAbsolutePath(): " + ext);
                                    ext = ext.substring(ext.lastIndexOf("."));
                                    Log.i(TAG + " ###", "ext: file.getAbsolutePath(): " + ext);

                                    String newPath = onlyPath + "/" + editText.getText().toString().trim() + ext;
                                    Log.i(TAG + " ###", "New Path: " + newPath);

                                    File newFile = new File(newPath);
                                    Log.i(TAG+" ###","renaming: in onClick(): newFile name: "+newFile.getName());
                                    boolean rename=false;
                                    try {
                                        rename = file.renameTo(newFile);
                                        Log.i(TAG+" ###","file name after renaming: "+file.getName());
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        Log.e(TAG + " ###", "Exception while renaming: " + e);
                                    }
                                    Log.i(TAG + " ###", "rename: " + rename);
                                    if (rename) {
                                        ContentResolver resolver = context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
                                        resolver.delete(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"),
                                                MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[]
                                                        {
                                                                file.getAbsolutePath()
                                                        });
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                                        intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(newFile));
                                        context.getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
                                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        Toast.makeText(context, "File Renamed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        //To show the instantaneous change in the name
                                        //Otherwise we have to close and reopen the app to see the change
                                        SystemClock.sleep(200);
                                        ((Activity) context).recreate();//automatically refreshes the activity

                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(context, "Process Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    //dismiss the dialog
                                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                            alertDialog.create().show();
                            bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });```

I have set the following permissions in the Manifest file-
```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_SYSTEM_SETTINGS" />```
````

Comment: You can not use the File class if you have a nice Uri. The mediastore has a .delete(uri) member. For rename use the .update(uri) member.

Comment: This delete method is not working and the app is crashing with error com.example.videoplayer has no access to content://media/external/video/media/83189

Comment: Well show your new code. And dont let your app crash by catching the exception.